# Windows: command line how to unzip file and rename it's content with zipped file name in current folder and sub folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, unzip

I would appreciate if I got help on this, I have the following script that unzip and rename the content with zipped file name, however it works in the current folder only, I need it work in subfolders as well!

```
@Echo off
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b  *.zip *.rar') DO (
     "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa
    for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir  /b *.html') do (
        ren "%%f" "%%~nI.html"
    ) 
)
```

it should search for any .zip file and unzip it and rename it's content with the zip file, example:

abc.zip ---> contains xyz.html

the result should be ----> abc.html

Comment: dir /b only lists files in the current folder. To search for subfolders, add /s